# html/php: how to refresh page without having to reset the scroll position?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a page where you can *Add Friends*.

```
1. Mark
   (Add Friend)
2. Sean
   (Add Friend)
3. Eddie
   (Add Friend)
...
```

This list is quite long. I want it that whenever the user clicks the `Add Friend` button, it will refresh the site and the `Add Friend` button becomes `Request Sent`. However, you can't do this unless you'd refresh the page so I tried adding `location.reload()` to the `Add Friend` code.

The only problem is that it will reset back to the top page and the user has to scroll down again.
How can I make the site refresh and will continue to the current *scroll position* as if nothing happened?

Comment: You can certainly update this list without reloading the page. I suggest you research AJAX, which would eliminate the need to scroll to a certain position on reload.

Comment: $("your class or id").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

Comment: and you can use javascript to just add friend and show it in your html

Comment: @mohade Thanks! I think I also can use a redirect. Like when I clink `add friend` it will link to the page where it adds friends then redirects back to the original page. I think there's a code for that? Like pressing `back` in the browser where it restores you to the scrolling point on the previous page?

Comment: You probably can pass the scroll position as a parameter in the link url.